# How to plot line chart with 5 data points and fixed 8 x-axis labels in chart js

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have to plot a line graph where x-axis labels will be fixed to 8 but data points can be  hundreds or less than 8 also.

The x-axis labels will be calculated based on startTime and stopTime

Start Time : 11:14

Stop Time: 11:41

I have to divide the duration between start and stop time by 8 to calculate the interval and then create 8 x axis labels with the interval as gap and render them in x axis.

This is the sample data for consumption in reverse order coming from api response.

```
const data =[
    {
        "ValueTimeStamp": "11:41",
        "MeterValue": "13.99",
        "Unit": "kWh"
    },
    {
        "ValueTimeStamp": "19:10",
        "MeterValue": "12.37",
        "Unit": "kWh"
    },
    {
        "ValueTimeStamp": "11:20",
        "MeterValue": "7.84",
        "Unit": "kWh"
    },
    {
        "ValueTimeStamp": "11:14",
        "MeterValue": "0.0",
        "Unit": "kWh"
    }
]
```

This is how currently graph is being plotted. You can see that last data point is not matching with the last x-axis label in graph. Last data point should extend till last x-axis label

[image]

This is our code for line chart.

Here XAxisLabels we have calculated using start time and stop time

And datasets is response coming from server

```
const LineChart = ({ XAxisLabels, datasets, yAxisMinScale, yAxisMaxScale }) => {
  const data = {
    labels: XAxisLabels,
    datasets: datasets,
  };

  const options = {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
      },
      line: {
        capBezierPoints: false,
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: "nearest",
      intersect: false,
    },
    stacked: false,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        position: "nearest",
        external: externalTooltipHandler,
      },
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        align: "end",
        onClick: () => {},
        color: "#9BD0F5",
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 10,
          boxHeight: 1,
          paddingRight: 100,
          filter: (item) => item.text !== "none",
        },
      },
    },

    scales: {
      y: {
        border: {
          color: "#655B96",
        },
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "left",
        min: yAxisMinScale,
        max: yAxisMaxScale,
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#655B96",
        },
        ticks: {
          count: 5,
          fontColor: "red",
        },
        offset: true,
      },
      x: {
        border: {
          color: "#655B96",
        },
        color: "red",
        offset: true,
        // borderColor: "red",
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          color: "#655B96",
        },
        title: {
          text: "Time",
          display: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return <Line options={options} data={data} />;
};
```

Please answer this question if any solution you know?